# Comunicación serial

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, serialport, pyserial

como puedo hacer la comunicación serial con un Arduino y python, ejecuto python desde Visual Studio Code, que es generado desde anaconda, en anaconda ya descargué la librería pyserial, pero al poner en el visual el import me genera un error

Comment: Bienvenido Manuel Ramirez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Bienvenido Manuel, por favor sigue las sujerencias de @PatricioMoracho, te ayudará mucho... Respecto a tu pregunta, sería bueno que edites tu pregunta y adjuntes tu código y tu error... nos vemos con las manos atadas cuando no tenemos información, tampoco podemos adivinar

Comment: Debes asegurarte de seleccionar el intérprete en el que has instalado PySerial  en VSCode, si usas la extensión oficial ms.python, se hace abajo a la izquierda, en la barra de estado: [Set up your environment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python). También en la paleta de comandos (pulsando `F1`) ingresando `Python: Select Interpreter` Busca y selecciona tu intérprete de Anaconda en la lista.